# SimpleXML parent - child issue

Tags: php, xml

i am having an issue with parsing an XML file using SimpleXML and PHP.

The XML file in question is provided by a third party and includes a number of child elements (going down multiple levels) within it. I know which elements i require and can see them within the XML file, but i just can't seem to get them to print using PHP.

Example XML feed for test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element1 xmlns="" release="8.1" environment="Production" lang="en-US">
    <Element2>
        <Element3>
            <Element4>
                <Element5>it worked</Element5>
            </Element4>
        </Element3>
    </Element2>
</Element1>
```

The file only includes one of each attribute so i can be very particular with the request, the code i have so far is below:

```
    $lib=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
    $make=$lib->Element1->Element2->Element3->Element4->Element5;
    print $make;
```

I have tried to look this up before asking, but the only solutions i can see are when the child attributes are unknown or there are multiple results for each request, which is not the case in this instance.

Any help or guidance would be greatly received.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, `$lib` *is* `Element1`.  So you just need to drop one of your references.  This:

```
$make=$lib->Element1->Element2->Element3->Element4->Element5;
```

Should become this:

```
$make=$lib->Element2->Element3->Element4->Element5;
```

Also, SimpleXML is an awful awful awful awful interface (considering that "Simple" is in the name and there is mass confusion about how to use it).  I would always recommend `DOMDocument` instead.

Comment: Thanks Sean, this worked a treat - will now research DOMDocument as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) as it will give you more flexibility e.g. Allow you to restrict results based on xml node attributes.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element1 xmlns="" release="8.1" environment="Production" lang="en-US">
    <Element2>
        <Element3>
            <Element4>
                <Element5>it worked</Element5>
            </Element4>
        </Element3>
    </Element2>
</Element1>');

$data=$xml->xpath('/Element1/Element2/Element3/Element4/Element5');
echo (string)$data[0]; //outputs 'it worked'
//this also works
$data=$xml->xpath('//Element5');
echo (string)$data[0]; //outputs 'it worked'
```